# "Apollonian" Circles on a Sphere

Tags: geodesic, spherical-geometry

The locus of a point $P$ such that there is a constant distance ratio $e=PA/PB$  between two fixed points $A$, $B$ in the plane is known to be the Apollonian Circle.

Correspondingly on a unit sphere what is the locus between points of long/lat $A(-L,0)$, $B(L,0)$ and $P(\operatorname{Long}P, \operatorname{Lat}P)$ along great circle arcs for a given $e$?

Is it is a small circle? If so what is its geodesic curvature $\kappa_g?$   The $\kappa_g$ should vanish for the prime meridian when $e=1.$

Constant $PA+PB$  *"ellipses"* were discussed here before ( @ achille hui ) ... Thanks in advance for literature if available, or, for a derivation/image if not available.

[image]

EDIT1:

Geodesic curvature $\kappa_g=1/R_g=\dfrac{\tan \gamma}{R}.$

Tangent length at any point is $R_g$ (red line segment) on the small circle and angle  $\gamma$ is a dimensionless angle parameter showing how far the small circle has deviated from the great circle or the equator. $\gamma=0$ for the great circle geodesic.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality we may assume that $A=(-1,0,0)$ and $B=(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha,0)$ and let $e>0$ be a real number. We want to find the locus of points $P=(x,y,z)$ on the unit sphere which has the property $\frac{PA}{PB}=e$. Here, $PA$ is the length of the shortest geodesic from $A$ to $P$. Similarly, for $PB$.

The arc $PA$ is measured by the angle $AOP$ say $\theta_1$ and the arc $PB$ is measured by the angle $BOP$ say $\theta_2$. And the points on the Apollonian circle satisfy the equation $\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}=e$ with the sphere.

Then from the standart $\Bbb{u}\cdot\Bbb{v}=|\Bbb{u}||\Bbb{v}|\cos\theta$ formula, we get $\theta_1=\arccos(-x)=\pi -\arccos(x)$ and $\theta_2=\arccos(x\cos\alpha+y\sin\alpha).$

Therefore, $P$ must line on the surface:
$$\frac{\pi -\arccos(x)}{\arccos(x\cos\alpha+y\sin\alpha)}=e \tag{1}$$
And the Apollonian circle is the intersection of that surface with the unit sphere. As a special case when $\alpha =0$, that is when $B=(1,0,0)$, this surface is the plane $x=\cos\frac{\pi}{e+1}$, as we found earlier, and the Apollonian circle is the intersection of that plane with the sphere. And it is really a circle.

Let us be a little sneaky and take  $P$ on the equator AB. Then $P=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0)$, $x=\cos\theta$ and $x\cos\alpha+y\sin\alpha=\cos(\theta-\alpha)$. And from the equation $(1)$ ve get $\theta=\frac{\pi+e\alpha}{e+1}$ and
$$P=(\cos(\frac{\pi+e\alpha}{e+1}),\sin(\frac{\pi+e\alpha}{e+1}),0)$$ on shorther geodesic and similarly we find
$$Q=(\cos(\frac{e\alpha -\pi}{e+1}),\sin(\frac{e\alpha -\pi}{e+1}),0)$$
on longer geodesic.
And the plane passing through them and perpendicular to $xy$-plane is
$$cos(\frac{e\alpha}{e+1})x+sin(\frac{e\alpha}{e+1})y=cos(\frac{\pi}{e+1}).\tag{2}$$
The Apollonian circle is the intersection of the plane $(2)$ and the unit sphere. Its radius is $R_e(A,B)=sin(\frac{\pi}{e+1})$ and its geodesic curvature is $\kappa_g=cot(\frac{\pi}{e+1})$.

But, the general formula is still open.

Comment: What if (A,B ) are not antipodal points?

Comment: Probably you have seen this: https://ijgeometry.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/9.-75-84.pdf. I thought about the steorographic projection too. Complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. So we need to stereographically project from /to the plane? What plane/s of intersection/s and  $\kappa_g−e$  relation can  we get from the link?

Comment: I don't know differential geometry well. what is Kappa g? Curvature? What do you mean? Do we need it here?

Comment: I have edited the question, hope it is clear. Angle $\gamma$ is zero for Greenwich meridian and $ 90^{\circ}$ at A or  B.